# Android Studio / Gradle debug build taking very long

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build

Creating debug build takes very long for me on - to my understanding - only small changes. E.g. I just updated from `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0` to `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.3.0`. After this, the build in total took 1m 31s. The top 3 build times from Build Analyzer are

```
:app:kaptDebugKotlin 29,0s 41,1%
:app:compileDebugKotlin 13,9s 19,8%
:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin 13,6s 19,3%
```

I am running on Windows 10 with an Intel Core i5 7600K @ 3.80GHz quad core with 32 GB RAM and only SSD storage. In my opinion my app is quite simple. Any way to further diagnose why the build is so slow? Or is this just normal on Android?

Comment: To me, this seems pretty normal. I am running Studio on a Pcie 3.0 SSD, 16GB Ram and 6core Ryzen. First start seems to take 1 minute sometimes. What if you downgrade the versions again? Is it better than?

Comment: It's not specific to that change, it's just the latest and concretes one I could mention as example. Meanwhile remembered my anti virus, so will check without it and compare.

Comment: I would not dig too deep into that and rather live with it.

Comment: well I compared with and without anti virus and got a 5 second difference which isn't much and might be just some luck. So yeah, seems like this are the normal build times ):